# Akka Typed ActorTestKit - How to send Terminated signal

Tags: akka, akka-testkit, akka-typed, akka-actor

I have an existing unit test that uses BehaviorTestKit to test the actor's behavior when it receives a Terminated signal.  I am able to send a Terminated signal to it like this:

```
val myParentTestKit = BehaviorTestKit(ParentActor())
myParentTestKit.signal(Terminated(myChildTestKit.ref))
```

This works great, and I am able to observe/assert the effects of the Terminated handling of the actor.

Now, some implementation details have changed (inter-actor messaging) that makes it no longer possible to use BehaviorTestKit.  I am trying to port this test to use ActorTestKit instead.  I am able to spawn the parent actor like this:

```
val myParent = myActorTestKit.spawn(ParentActor())
```

However I can't figure out how to send the Terminated signal to it.

What is the correct way to send a Terminated signal when using ActorTestKit instead of BehaviorTestKit?

Answer (score 0):

The actor testkit actually runs the actor "for real", so the way to trigger `Terminated` is to stop the actor. That can be done either through an explicit stop message in the protocol of the actor for which the actor returns `Behaviors.stopped` or when started through the testkit using `myActorTestKit.stop(actorRef)`.

Comment: Hmmm...  But I think the only way that the parent actor will actually receive that Terminated signal naturally upon the child's death is if it is "watching" the child actor.  Setting this up would involve making a different part of the production code spawn the child, rather than the test kit doing it.  That sounds more like a larger integration test, and not really in the spirit of a unit test.  Is there any way, using ActorTestKit, to manually make the parent actor "watch" the child actor (both of which were spawned via the test kit) from the test code?

Comment: Ah, I didn't infer that it was about a parent watching a child, for that it would either have to be the parent killing the actor or sending it a stop message after spawning and watching it.

Comment: There is no way to force an actor to watch another but you could possibly design for that to be something you can override for the test.

Comment: watchWith may be a better option as it can use a message from the actors own protocol, that you can send manually to the actor in a test

Comment: Yeah in general I advise to use `watchWith` over `watch` (largely for this reason).  It's also generally possible to test inter-actor messaging with the BehaviorTestKit, though your test suite will take some responsibility for delivering the messages.